# Let in javascript is block scope. So how did this code does work?

Tags: javascript, scope, let

Let is  block scope . But I have found this codes output wired. how the let declared in window can be accessed in another function?

```
let wind ="something blah blah";
function trial(){
console.log(wind);
}
trial();
```

Comment: Because that function is *also* in the same scope.  It would be pretty limiting if functions couldn't access anything outside of themselves...

Comment: It is defined in the outer scope. So it is accessible from the function.

Comment: see this for discussion of variable scope https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript